# Is it possible to re-run the Magento translation once an AJAX call has been made?

Tags: ajax, localisation, language

I'm trying to re-run the string replace that Magento runs upon load for language translation. The reason for this is I have injected HTML (via AJAX) that happens at any point after the page load has completed.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about the php one `__()` or the JS one?

The PHP translation NO, because it works server side, but you can translate the stuff in the AJAX request.

The JS one is injected here:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/js/translate.phtml
```

And I think if generate a second `Translate` object it might work.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that method and if that doesn't work, I will translate the data before it gets sent in the AJAX call